# Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

Is it possible to add attributes at runtime or to change the value of an attribute at runtime?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Attributes are static metadata. Assemblies, modules, types, members, parameters, and return values aren't first-class objects in C# (e.g., the `System.Type` class is merely a reflected representation of a type). You can get an instance of an attribute for a type and change the properties if they're writable but that won't affect the attribute as it is applied to the type.

Answer (score 72):

This really depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

The [System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) stuff can be used to add attributes to types, properties and object instances, and it has the limitation that you have to use it to retrieve those properties as well.  If you're writing the code that consumes those attributes, and you can live within those limitations, then I'd definitely suggest it.

As far as I know, the PropertyGrid control and the visual studio design surface are the only things in the BCL that consume the TypeDescriptor stuff.  In fact, that's how they do about half the things they really need to do.

Comment: Actually, most data-binding uses `TypeDescriptor` - not just `PropertyGrid`.

Comment: Any workaround to add property-metadata attributes in a Silverlight project (where `TypeDescriptor` and `TypeDescriptionProvider` aren't implemented?

Comment: Important to note, TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes() does not handle duplicate attributes. It only selects the last of the attribute type. Ex `[Attr(1), Attr(2), Attr(3)]` only `Attr(3)` is found.

Answer (score 12):

You can't. One workaround might be to generate a derived class at runtime and adding the attribute, although this is probably bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 11):

Well, just to be different, I found an article that references using Reflection.Emit to do so.

Here's the link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dotnetattributes.aspx , you will also want to look into some of the comments at the bottom of the article, because possible approaches are discussed.

Comment: Note that you can create attributes at runtime with the  Reflection.Emit classes, BUT you can bind them to classes you have built with the Emit package and not to existing ones.

Comment: @Hopeless, you may subclass `YourClass` into `YourRuntimeClassWithAttributes`.

Comment: @Motes not sure what you mean, my classes are all defined beforehand, that means all the base classes (that my classes inherit) should also be defined/determined beforehand. I cannot think of any way for it to be involved with something dynamically created using Reflection.Emit.

Comment: @Hopeless, if you wanted to add attributes dynamically to an existing class `YourClass`, you could subclass it at runtime and generate an identical class with a slightly different name that also has the desired dynamically created attributes, and polymorphism will allow type checking code to still identify your baseclass.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not.

Attributes are meta-data and stored in binary-form in the compiled assembly (that's also why you can only use simple types in them).

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so.  Even if I'm wrong, the best you can hope for is adding them to an entire Type, never an *instance* of a Type.

Comment: TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object, Attribute[]) adds class-level attributes to the target component instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something to be able to added dynamically, c# attributes aren't the way. Look into storing the data in xml. I recently did a project that i started w/ attributes, but eventually moved to serialization w/ xml.

Comment: maybe it's not a beautiful way but it's the way many other libraries choose to use, and to customize those libraries' behaviors, we have a requirement to play with reflection =)) really a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to? Attributes give extra information for reflection, but if you externally know which properties you want you don't need them.

You could store meta data externally relatively easily in a database or resource file.

Comment: Boilerplate elimination.  Wouldn't it be handy if you could have a class automagically generate attributes based on the code within the class?  I'm trying to figure out something like this to reduce boilerplate in SQL CLR objects.  Would be easy in other languages ... see http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html

Answer (score 1):

Like mentionned in a comment below by Deczaloth, I think that metadata is fixed at compile time. I achieve it by creating a dynamic object where I override GetType() or use GetCustomType() and writing my own type. Using this then you could...

I tried very hard with System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor without success. That does not means it can't work but I would like to see code for that.

In counter part, I wanted to change some Attribute values.
I did 2 functions which work fine for that purpose.

```
        // ************************************************************************
        public static void SetObjectPropertyDescription(this Type typeOfObject, string propertyName,  string description)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeOfObject)[propertyName];
            var att = pd.Attributes[typeof(DescriptionAttribute)] as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (att != null)
            {
                var fieldDescription = att.GetType().GetField("description", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (fieldDescription != null)
                {
                    fieldDescription.SetValue(att, description);
                }
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public static void SetPropertyAttributReadOnly(this Type typeOfObject, string propertyName, bool isReadOnly)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeOfObject)[propertyName];
            var att = pd.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)] as ReadOnlyAttribute;
            if (att != null)
            {
                var fieldDescription = att.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (fieldDescription != null)
                {
                    fieldDescription.SetValue(att, isReadOnly);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: With those methods you change the value of the Attribute, as a separate entity. The Attribute of THE Property remains unchanged!

Comment: That is possible, in fact I already done a dynamic object (where you can add/remove dynamic properties at runtime and it is highly possible my code come from that small library). Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with this situation, yet another solution might be **questioning you code design** and search for a more object-oriented way. For me, struggling with unpleasant reflection work arounds is the last resort. And my first reaction to this situation would be **re-designing the code**. Think of the following code, which tries to solve the problem that you have to add an attribute to a third-party class you are using.

```
class Employee {} // This one is third-party.
```

And you have code like

```
var specialEmployee = new Employee();
// Here you need an employee with a special behaviour and 
// want to add an attribute to the employee but you cannot.
```

The solution might be extracting a class inheriting from the `Employee` class and decorating it with your attribute:

```
[SpecialAttribute]
class SpecialEmployee : Employee 
{
}
```

When you create an instance of this new class

```
var specialEmployee = new SpecialEmployee();
```

you can *distinguish* this `specialEmployee` object from other `employee` objects. If appropriate,  you may want to make this `SpecialEmployee` a private nested class.