# How do I assign .Net attributes programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)

Is it possible to assign .net Attribute to class/method programmatically?

For example:
Can I decorate my custom .net com classes with Guid/ProgId attributes taken from external file? Something like:

```
typeof(MyComObject).AssignAttribute(new GuidAttribute("..."));
```

instead of hardcode like:

```
[Guid("...")]
class MyComObject
{
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Only if you create the class itself at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. `ICustomTypeDescriptor` allows to almost anything you want to almost every part of a class (which might not even exist for that matter), but this particular interface might not be used by whatever system you're trying to feed your object to. `PropertyGrid` uses this interface extensively, though.