# Adding dynamically a attribut to a c# class

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have an existing C# class that I cannot modify, but only use it.
By example:

```
public class Test {}
```

I would like to add **dynamically** an attribute (MyAttribute) to this class Test, like:

```
[MyAttribute(TestMode)]
public class Test {}
```

Is it possible in C# and how?

Note: of course, I can derive from this Test class and add declaratively the attribute, but it means to create a new class, and I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say **dynamically**? Do you want to add the attribute at runtime?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c

Comment: I second Daniel here. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I want to add the attribute at runtime

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what attributes are. Attributes are information about a `Class` and therefore it's absolutely not related with dynamically add information to an `Object`.

What do you want do do? I'm sure the solution is something else.

Comment: A third party system uses a specific attribute to recognize in an assembly some classes its needs. By adding this attribute to the Test class, this one will be recognized too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attributes are compiled into metadata and cannot be added at runtime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.80).aspx