# Set assembly level attribute conditionally

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, assemblies

I would like to set an assembly level attribute conditionally based on a value read from my config file. Is it possible?

I read that attributes are static metadata and so while the data itself can be changed at run-time, the changes have no applicability after the application has started.

What other alternatives do I have?

**Update**

*My objective: What I am trying to do*

I am using a TraceAttribute to trace all method entry and exit points. I would like to switch on or off this attribute at the assembly level based on a value from the config file. I'd like to have it off most times but only turn it on in emergency situations to collect evidence of a problem from a certain environment.

Comment: Please explain why you want to set an attribute based on some configuration value. What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've updated my question to include by goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is more than answered here:
[Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)

I'm still not sure why do you need to bind an assembly level attribute and a config key, but you can pass the config key to the attribute's constructor/property and resolve its value inside the attribute logic. It will look like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class TraceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TraceAttribute(string traceConfigKey)
    {
        var keyValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[traceConfigKey];

        DoTracing = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue) && bool.Parse(keyValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this property for your tracing conditional logic.
    /// </summary>
    public bool DoTracing { get; private set; }
}
```

Then in your AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: Trace("DoTracing")]
```

And config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DoTracing" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

As another solution, if you use an existing attribute, and you cannot customize it, you can also add a conditional compilation symbol to your project properties, then write:

```
#if TRACE
[assembly: Trace()]
#endif
```

but it needs the project recompilation, of course.

Comment: That's neat! Now, why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
#ifdef TRACE
[TraceAttribute()]
#endif
MethodBeingTraced()
{
}
```

define the TRACE variable at a project configuration level