# Is it possible to add attributes to external structures?

Tags: c#, com, attributes, binaryformatter

I'm getting some external structures from COM library.

I want to use BinaryFormatter and just get byte array as package. But I need special attribute on structure to satisfy BinaryFormatter.

It's not my structure so how can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are metadata class, that are included to the assemply at compile time, So it is impossible to add attiributes to a class dynamically at runtime, check this questions:

- [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)