# Dynamic data annotation in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, data-annotations

i am creating instance of class by using Activator in c# mvc.
but i have to add attribute for example

> [required]

dynamically to the instance.
so how can i do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)

Comment: simply, you **can't.**

Comment: @MaTya You cannot add attributes at runtime to already existent type. Maybe you will benefit from approach similar to Fluent Validation project (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). If you need dynamically determine input validation rules you can take for example a Builder pattern and combined with Fluent Validation you can achieve the goal. Anyways providing more background will help people here to help you find an answer.

Comment: thanks but can i add attribute when i creating object of class? becoz i creating class using xml data. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/04/23/generating-aspnet-mvc-view-controls-according-to-xml-configurations/  plz see this for reference here i want to add attribute.