# Make class serializable while runtime

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I have a small Library where the user can set and get properties by using an generic interface. So the user can set every object he or she wants.

Than I have a method to save the properties to the file-system using the `BinaryFormatter`. With native types like `string` or `DateTime` or ... everything works fine. But if the user has a custom class like

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

than I get an Exception, that the `class` Person is not market as `Serializable`. If I write the `[Serializable]` attribute about my class it just works fine.

My question is now: Is there a way that I can declare a class as `Serializable` in runtime? So if the user forgot to do so, I can try it?

The code for the Serialization looks like:

```
public void Save(string saveFilePath)
{
    byte[] binaryData;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, AllProperties);
        binaryData = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(saveFilePath, binaryData);
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c It would be a bad practice as well I would say

Comment: you can make use libraries like http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html or xmlserialisation would work too. but as derape said, it's bad practice to do that

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Than the user will have to take responsibility for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes in C# are static metadata. They can't be injected at runtime. What you can do is use reflection on a `System.Type` to search that metadata at runtime.

The user declaring the class will have to do so at compile-time.