# How to attach to decimal datatype DisplayFormatAttribute automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework v6.1.3 (code first) and ASP.NET MVC v5.2.3

I know I can use *DisplayFormatAttribute* in a *decimal* datatype like this

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
public decimal Foo { get; set; }
```

Now what I need is to apply this attribute **automatically** to every *decimal* in each entity.

Is this possible?

I had a similar requirement that every decimal must have a precision of 20,8 and I solved this using this code

```
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      // Set all decimals data types by default as Decimal(20, 8)
      modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>().Configure(c => c.HasPrecision(20, 8));
   }
}
```

So I wonder if is it possible to assign automatically the *DisplayFormatAttribute*.

Comment: Thank you Fran and Sergey Berezovskiy your answers solved partially the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a deep search I found the answer

**It can't be done**

Here's the answer

[Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can create display template for decimal type and put it to *Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates* folder:

```
@model System.Decimal
<span>  
    @Model.ToString("n2")
</span>
```

And in view just use `DisplayFor` or `DisplayForModel` methods:

```
@Model.DisplayFor(m => m.Foo)
```

Further reading: [What are Display and Editor Templates?](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a DisplayTemplate for the decimal type is every decimal is going to be formatted the same way.

from [ASP.NET MVC display and editor templates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

Defining custom templates

We can override the default templates by placing our custom display templates into the path Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/.cshtml. They are structured like any MVC partial view. An example usage could be adding a dollar sign to the front of a decimal’s value.
Model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
}
```

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/decimal.cshtml

```
@model decimal

    @{
        IFormatProvider formatProvider =
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        <span class="currency">@Model.ToString("C", formatProvider)</span>
    }
```

view

```
@model TestModel

@Html.DisplayFor(e => e.Money)
```